# How to convert a log2(n) based value to n shifts in a #define statement in C?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a definition of the following type in C:

```
#define NUM_OF_CHANNELS 8
```

I want to refer to this definition and use it also for shift operations, such as

```
a = b >> 3
```

The value 3 comes from `log2(8) = 3`.

So I wish there was something like

```
#define NUM_OF_CHANNELS_SHIFT LOG2(NUM_OF_CHANNELS)
a = b >> NUM_OF_CHANNELS_SHIFT
```

But obviously the above definition doesn't work. Is there a nifty way to get this accomplished?

Comment: If `b` is known to be nonnegative, simply use `b / NUM_OF_CHANNELS`. Any decent compiler will optimize it to a shift.

Comment: And `NUM_OF_CHANNELS` is always a power of `2`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, ha, I didn't think it was that easy. I just checked and it even works if there's no optimization. I am using gcc.

Comment: @SparKot, yes it is always a power of 2.

Comment: @Hansel well, fortunately it does work even without optimisation... Otherwise it would mean that your compiler is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Most commonly, you would just do the defines the other way around:

```
#define NUM_OF_CHANNELS_SHIFT   3
#define NUM_OF_CHANNELS  (1 << NUM_OF_CHANNELS_SHIFT)
```

This forces you to keep the number of channels a power of two.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by @EricPostpischil in a comment:

> If `b` is known to be nonnegative, simply use `b / NUM_OF_CHANNELS`. Any
> decent compiler will optimize it to a shift.

The compiler will translate the following C code into assembly code performing a 3-bit long right-shift.

```
#define NUM_OF_CHANNELS 8
a = b / NUM_OF_CHANNELS;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the answer to your question or you can request @EricPostpischil to post an answer for you to accept as a courtesy.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, would you mind posting an answer? Someone seems to have suggested some edits to my post but it appears I don't have enough credits to review the suggestions.